# Get android toolbar child views in fragment

Tags: android

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp">
    <!-- Color is Brown 500 -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <!--android:paddingTop="2dp"/-->
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:elevation="7sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </include>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i access the ProgressBar in the toolbar and set it to visible in my fragment code?

I tried:

```
AppCompatActivity act = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (act.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) act.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
        progress = (ProgressBar)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_progress_bar);
    }
```

But getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with

```
  toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

for me it works! I have an ImageView inside a Toolbar